# ListView Not updating if a delete an item

Tags: xaml, data-binding, windows-8.1

I have a listView which is set to `Mode=TwoWay`, which i thought was suppose to refresh the views, if the underlying data changed.

However, while the item is deleted correctly, the item still remains on the list, until I exit and return to the page.

Xaml:

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Path=items, Mode=TwoWay}" >
    <DataTemplate>
       ...

        <Button   x:Name="btn_delete_item" Click="btn_delete_item_Click" >

        </Button>
```

Behind code:

```
 private void btn_delete_item_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Button button = sender as Button;
        itemType item = button.DataContext as itemType;

        items.Remove(item);
    }
```

Comment: `Mode=TwoWay` is not necessary, but your `items` collection should notify about changes. You might use an ObservableCollection to achieve this.

Comment: @Clemens my `items` is just a `List<itemType>`. I will have a read about `ObservableCollection`. Im suprised Lists dont support databinding fully.

Comment: And please note that there are [naming conventions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229043.aspx) for (public) identifiers in C#. Both types and properties should use `PascalCasing`, not `camelCasing`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In order to fully support data binding, your `Items` collection must notify about changes, i.e. whether items are added, removed, replaced or moved. This notification is done by implementing the `INotifyCollectionChanged` interface. The framework's `List<T>` type does not implement this interface, but `ObservableCollection<T>` does.

So you could simply change the type of your `Items` property:

```
public ObservableCollection<ItemType> Items { get; set; }
```

Comment: I tried this based on your comment. And it works great. It even has cool animations to the removing from list.
I just cast it using `new ObservableCollection<itemType>(myitemlistsource)` when setting `items`.